# Use EditContext without using @bind-Value - Blazor

Tags: c#, blazor

#### Current situation

Imagine a self written Dropdown component, which takes the common `For` paramter and the `@bind-Value`. The component is used within an editcontext, which marks the component as `invalid` (per css) if invalid. This behaviour works fine, as long as the @bind-Value attribute is used.

#### Problem

However, sometimes the `ValueChanged` EventCallback needs to be listened to seperatly from th e `Value` prop.

#### Example Code

```html
<!--Does work -->
<DataRowDropDownComponent Values="_productTypes.Select(gg => gg.Label)"
    @bind-Value="ArticleEntity.ProductType"
    For="() => ArticleEntity.ProductType"></DataRowDropDownComponent>

<!--Does not work -->
<DataRowDropDownComponent Values="_goodsGroups.Select(gg => gg.Label)"
    Value="ArticleEntity.GoodsGroup"
    For="() => ArticleEntity.GoodsGroup"
    T="string"
    ValueChanged="GoodsGroupChanged"></DataRowDropDownComponent>
```

#### Current situation / research

Cause of the problem is that the `_fieldintentiefer` of type `FieldIdentifier` is null. This leads to following error:

`Error: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'obj') at System.OrdinalCaseSensitiveComparer.GetHashCode(String obj) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.FieldIdentifier.GetHashCode() at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary2...`

If any further code is needed, please let me know in the comments. The component inherits from an component base. The other components e. g. an Input component works just fine. It seems that I'm missing some vital info on how the `@bind-Value` is handled together with an FieldIdentifier.

#### Edit 1:

GoodsGroupChanged:

```cs
public async Task GoodsGroupChanged(string val)
{
    if(ArticleEntity is not null && val is not null)
    {
        var value = val.ToString() + "";
        GetAndSetNavigation(value, NavigationTypes.GoodsGroup);
        await LoadProductGroups(value);
    }
}
public void GetAndSetNavigation(string label, NavigationTypes navType)
{
    if(ArticleEntity?.Entity is AssortmentArticle aa)
    {
        aa.Navigation = navType switch {
            NavigationTypes.ProductGroup => _productGroups.Find(n => n.Label == label),
            NavigationTypes.GoodsGroup => _goodsGroups.Find(n => n.Label == label),
            NavigationTypes.ProductType => null,
            _ => null
        };
    }
}

private async Task LoadProductGroups(string label)
{
//busines logic id rather not share --> sets the the _productType list for another component
}
```

Comment: Can you share the GoodsGroupChanged method.

Comment: What version of DotNet?

Comment: When you use Value and ValueChanged, in the GoodsGroupChanged method you need to set the value of the variable declared for Value i.e. `ArticleEntity.GoodsGroup` even if it is null.

Comment: But the error message seems like an entity framework error message, add 
`ArticleEntity.GoodsGroup=val` on the first line of GoodsGroupChanged and see if you get a different error.

Comment: Without seeing the component code for `DataRowDropDownComponent`, this is a bit of educated guesswork.

When you wire up the Bind parameters manually, you normally need to provide a `ValueExpression` parameter.  `InputBase` derived components use this to contruct a `FieldIdentifier`.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis Adding the `ValueExpression` manually fixed it - thanks

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the component code for `DataRowDropDownComponent`, this is a bit of educated guesswork. When you wire up the Bind parameters manually, you normally need to provide a `ValueExpression` parameter. `InputBase` derived components use this to contruct a `FieldIdentifier`.